# Transfer Store from Enterprise to Go

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-go

Is there any way(fast and easy) to move store(database and design) from Magento Enterprise to Magento Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.  Magento/eBay have no incentive to provide this, and I've never heard of anyone trying it themselves.

Magento Go [has an API](http://go.magento.com/api-doc) so you might be able to program something yourself, but an enterprise system has functionality that a Go system will not have, making a complete transfer impossible.